# The problem with displaying imask with material ui TextField

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, react-hooks, mask

If I enter One character and remove the focus, the Textfield breaks.
I guess mask problems
As shown in the picture
My code https://codesandbox.io/s/happy-blackwell-5sigw?file=/src/App.js:0-610

[image]

```
import { TextField } from "@material-ui/core";
import { IMaskMixin } from "react-imask";
import { useForm } from "react-hook-form";

const IMaskPhoneInput = IMaskMixin(({ ...props }) => {
  return <TextField {...props} />;
});

export default function App() {
  const {
    register,
  } = useForm();

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <IMaskPhoneInput
        autoFocus
        fullWidth
        mask={"+{7} (000) 000-00-00"}
        color="primary"
        label={"Телефон"}
        placeholder={"+7 (950) 356-55-44"}
        {...register("phone")}
      />
    </div>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried including the shrink prop?

```
<TextField InputLabelProps={{ shrink: true }} />
```

This is per the documentation at https://mui.com/components/text-fields/ under limitations

> Shrink
>
> > The input label "shrink" state isn't always correct. The input label is supposed to shrink as soon as the input is displaying something. In some circumstances, we can't determine the "shrink" state (number input, datetime input, Stripe input). You might notice an overlap.

> To workaround the issue, you can force the "shrink" state of the label.
> `<TextField InputLabelProps={{ shrink: true }} />` or `<InputLabel shrink>Count</InputLabel>`

Comment: Thanks for your answer. The screenshot should be input as plain text. Text in images can be difficult to read, especially on mobile, and metered or slow connections can waste too much data on responses that are not required to be in image form. Also, images are not accessibility friendly. Please edit to include information from the image as text. Please refer to the help pages, linked to at the top of every page, for other SO guidelines. Aside from that, excellent use of a link to documentation, and example coded solution. Recommend markdown "quoting" that passage, by prefixing a ·>· character

Comment: Thank you @SherylHohman for the guidance. Updated!